# How to group numbers by size

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

I have *n* different numbers and I want to sort them into *k* groups, such that any number in group 1 is smaller than any number in group 2, and anyone in group 2 smaller than anyone in group 3 and so on until group *k* (the numbers do not have to be sorted inside each group). I'm asked to design an algorithm that runs in *O(n log k)*, but I can only come up with *O(n^2)* ones.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you have a look at the Wiki page on sorting, in particular the Bucket Sort algorithm? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: Any other constraints? As stated, you could just put all numbers in group 1 and leave all others empty.

Comment: Well the constrains are that each bucket needs to have the same amount of elements (in this case n/k) and it needs to run in O(n log k) time.

Comment: This seems similar to quick sort, finding k-1 pivots to separate the array into k groups. The issue is finding the k-1 pivot points with a low time complexity. I'm thinking something similar to [median of medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians), but that gets complicated. There may be a way to do this with something like heap sort.

Comment: @Jaco - the issue with bucket sort is that the buckets will not be the same size. The goal in this case is to separate the array of n number into k groups of equal size (except for the last group).

Comment: @rcgldr, you need to create a mapping function that maps your array into n number of k groups of equal size. It only works if you know the distribution of your numbers, however, I don't think you can do this in O(n log k) without knowing this.

Comment: Another pdf file about [median of medians](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2110/2009su/Lectures/examples/MedianFinding.pdf). Looking at std::sort quick sort algorithm, it's using a n/9 (instead of n/5) method, that in turn uses a n/3 method. I don't know if this is guaranteed to be O(n) worst case.

Comment: @liwuen please show your current algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the problem statement is to separate n *different* numbers into k groups. This would get more complicated if there were duplicates as noted in the wiki links below.

Any process that can determine the kth smallest element with less than O(n log(k)) complexity could be used k-1 times to produce an array of the elements corresponding to the boundaries between k groups. Then a single pass could be made on the array, doing a binary search of the boundary array to split up the array into k groups with O(n log(k)) complexity. However, it seems that at least one algorithm to find the kth smallest element also partitions the array, so that alone could be used to create the k groups.

A unordered partial sort using a selection algorithm with worst case time O(n) is possible. Wiki links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Unordered_partial_sorting

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_heap#Applications

Comment: Thank you for the comment! After reading this it became clear how to do it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this by modifying the Bucket sort algorithm, below I have included a JavaScript implementation, see [Github](https://gist.github.com/tixxit/811196) for further details on the source code. This implementation uses 16 buckets, you will have to modify it to allow for `k` buckets and you can  omit the sorting of buckets itself. One approach would be to use `2^p` buckets where p is the smallest integer that satisfies `2^p < n`. This algorithm will run in *O(n log k)*

```js
// Copyright 2011, Tom Switzer
// Under terms of ISC License: http://www.isc.org/software/license

/**
 * Sorts an array of integers in linear time using bucket sort.
 * This gives a good speed up vs. built-in sort in new JS engines
 * (eg. V8). If a key function is given, then the result of
 * key(a[i]) is used as the integer value to sort on instead a[i].
 *
 * @param a A JavaScript array.
 * @param key A function that maps values of a to integers.
 * @return The array a.
 */
function bsort(a, key) {
  key = key || function(x) {
    return x
  };
  var len = a.length,
    buckets = [],
    i, j, b, d = 0;
  for (; d < 32; d += 4) {
    for (i = 16; i--;)
      buckets[i] = [];
    for (i = len; i--;)
      buckets[(key(a[i]) >> d) & 15].push(a[i]);
    //This implementation uses 16 buckets, you will need to modify this
    for (b = 0; b < 16; b++)
      //The next two lines sort each bucket, you can leave it out
      for (j = buckets[b].length; j--;)
        a[++i] = buckets[b][j];
  }
  return a;
}


var array = [2, 4, 1, 5, 3];

$('#result').text(bsort(array, function(x) {
  return x
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use K-selection algorithm with partition function from QuickSort - [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).
Let's K is power of 2 for simplicity.
At the first stage we make partition of N elements, it takes O(N) ~ p* N time, where p is some constant
At the second stage we recursively make 2 partitions of N/2 elements, it takes 2* p* N/2 = p*N time.
At the third stage we make 4 partitions of N/4 elements, it takes 4*p*N/4 = p*N time.
...
At the last stage we make K partitions of N/K elements, it takes K* p* N/K = p*N  time.

Note there are Log(K) stages, so overall time is Log(K) * p * N = O(N*Log(K)

Comment: Thank you for your help! After discussing with the professor, this was one approach he suggested! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help, basically a quickselect (or any linear time sorting algorithm that finds the k-th statistic in linear time is enough) and, after running it k-1 times, we make a binary search over the original array to split the elements into groups, getting O(nlog k).

Also, if you don't want to make a binary search, in the quickselect, you can also separate the elements and find the statistic in each subset! @rcgldr, @MBo thank you for your ideas!